# Getting values from SeekBar in android

Tags: java, android

How do I get values from a `SeekBar`?

- I have a code of a class that has three SeekBars (`PRICEbar`)
- I want to pass the values of these SeekBars to next Activity (screen)
  as Intents
- I know how toimplement OnClickListener but how can I extract the
  values from the SeekBars?

**ex:** if `PRICEbar` is pointing to value 10 ... I need to get the value of 10

**Filters.java**

```
public class Filters extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener{

    // declare text objects variables
    private SeekBar PRICEbar; 
    private TextView PRICEtextProgress,DISTANCEtextProgress, RATINGtextProgress;
    Button back;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // load the layout
        setContentView(R.layout.filters);   

        PRICEbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.PRICEseekBarID); // make seekbar object
        PRICEbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); 
        PRICEbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                PRICEtextProgress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.PRICEtextViewProgressID);
                PRICEtextProgress.setText("Price:: Rs "+progress);
                seekBar.setMax(100);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (seekBar == PRICEbar)
            PRICEtextProgress.setText("Price:: Rs "+progress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The `SeekBar` class is a subclass of `ProgressBar`, which contains a [`getProgress()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#getProgress%28%29) method.

Calling `PRICEbar.getProgress()` will return the value you are looking for.