# talkback for seekbar value?

Tags: android, seekbar, talkback

I'm creating a music app and I'm currently working on talkback.

When controlling an app's seekbar for a position, the device is saying like "60% seek control" instead of saying the actual value like "2:30".
How to fix it?

I was trying to use below methods but I couldn't make it work.

```
onInitializeAccessibilityEvent()
onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo()
onPopulateAccessibilityEvent()
onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent()
announceForAccessibility()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227722/getting-values-from-seekbar-in-android/19227945

Comment: That is not what i'm looking for. I am talking about "talkback". when I am sliding the seekbar, I want that talkback should say the actual value.